# Error message Strict standards in Joomla Website

Tags: php, joomla2.5

Joomla Website URL: http://gero-teufert.de/impro_for_biz3/index.php

We are getting several errors on this Joomla Website since we updated the PHP version.

Errors Like:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not
>   be called statically in
>   /var/www/l3s8433/html/impro_for_biz3/includes/application.php on line
>   540

We have solved the errors on our local machine by editing the php.ini file and Joomla config file but since we do not have access to this file on server, we could not do it.

Is there anyway we could solve these errors by editing Joomla files as we were were able to solve some errors and few are still left.

Comment: This **must** be a dupe, but I cannot find any relevant question...

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because your error reporting is set to **On** in your `configuration.php`. To fix go to "global config" and go  to  `/server/ Error reporting/` set to **none**. This should work.

Comment: Thanks Tornado..

We did set it to simple and even none but it did not solve the issue.

We were able to fix errors on homepage by editing the file but the errors still appear on this page

http://gero-teufert.de/impro_for_biz3/referenzen/kundenreferenzen.html

Comment: @Pankaj check your components(like `com_content`) somewhere you are enable the error reporting on for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting service uses FastCGI, you must have your own copy of `php.ini` (maybe with a slightly different name) somewhere in your FTP account. Alternatively, you should be able to configure PHP with a [.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) file.

If it runs PHP as Apache module, you can use `.htaccess`. It's worth nothing that the syntax is different and you cannot use constants like `E_ALL`:

```
php_value error_reporting -1
```

If it's using another SAPI, please provide the appropriate info.

*BTW, you aren't actually solving the errors. You are just hiding them ;-)*

Comment: Hello Alvaro,

Thanks for your reply!

Apparently, the client does not wish to share the cPanel details..

We have solved most errors but few still left on this link
Thanks Tornado..

We did set it to simple and even none but it did not solve the issue.

We were able to fix errors on homepage by editing the file but the errors still appear on this page

http://gero-teufert.de/impro_for_biz3/referenzen/kundenreferenzen.html

Comment: I understand you are talking about Joomla settings. I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Open **configuration.php** in the main joomla directory. Set `$error_reporting` to `'6135'`.

For me it was line 23, and after editing it looked like this:

```
public $error_reporting = '6135';
```